# Does Mercurial support empty commit messages?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, version-control

Is there a way to configure Mercurial to allow for empty commit messages?  If you try `hg commit` through the CLI without entering a commit message, the commit is canceled with: `abort: empty commit message`.

Now, I know that committing without a message is usually considered bad form, but does Mercurial allow it at all?

Comment: it's bad form for a reason, and I'm curious about a valid use case for it, if you don't mind sharing.

Comment: I was working on a project where I was the only person using the repo, and the IDE liked to make changes when it closed.  I didn't want to leave uncommitted changes sitting in the repository, so I had intended to use empty messages for those instances; not really that big of a deal.  Now it's more out of curiosity than anything else.

Comment: I usually use "Derp." when I'm too lazy to come up with valid commit message.

Comment: @derekerdmann It's all nice and good to be organized with your commit messages, but some projects really are small enough that they are unnecessary. But forget about that, my question is: What's the point of forcing a message? The user will just enter a dummy message anyway, and you will have gained nothing.

Comment: You _can_ have an empty comment if your repository was imported from another VCS --- I just found one and it caused no end of problems. This is not necessarily useful, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use just a space, but I'd really discourage it:

```
hg commit -m " "
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that would be the result. Hoping there's another solution.

Comment: @tonfa Are you sure? Has that been documented anywhere?

Comment: @derekerdmann No it's not documented, and I'm pretty sure we won't change the command line for that.

Comment: @tonfa Oh, I didn't realized you'd worked on it. Why didn't you say so before?  Thanks  a ton!  Looks like a space is the only way to go.

Comment: @Patrick Just an FYI - using an actual space doesn't work; you need to have some other placeholder instead.  I'm leaving your answer as the accepted one because it's still the right idea.

Comment: @derekerdmann - Works for me under Mercurial 1.5.3.  What version are you using?  Maybe they've changed it in more recent versions to strip out whitespace as well.

Comment: @Patrick Steele - I'm running 1.6, that must be the difference.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is that you don't want to enter the -m "blah" part you can always set up an alias. e.g. in hgrc

```
[alias]
qcommit = commit -m "quick commit - no message"
```

If you don't like qcommit then you can alias to commit instead i.e.

```
[alias]
commit = commit -m "quick commit - no message"
```

this won't help you with TortoiseHG however which presumebly validates its entry fields before passing data to mercurial iteslf

Comment: `qcommit` is probably a bad idea as far as the name of an alias goes. Commands starting with `q` are normally mercurial queue (MQ) commands

Comment: agree the whole feature is probably a bad idea anyway though