# Mercurial + TortoiseHg -> Empty commit message

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using **Mercurial** with **TortoiseHg** on Windows. And because some repositories (not all) are merely a space to sync files, I would like to have an **empty commit message**

[image: Using dots as "empty commit message"]

Entering a dot in the comment field seems to work, but it's annoying. Is there some sort of automatical "." commit message, or even an empty one?

I own the server with the hgweb.config and the hgwebdir.wsgi so I guess there should be a solution that works...

*Disclaimer: Please do not start a discussion about the importance of commit message! I specifically want this **not** to happen! I use commit messages for source code repositories, but not for this task, no further explanation necessary!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure mercurial, empty commit messages are not posible (see [Does Mercurial support empty commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343424/does-mercurial-support-empty-commit-messages)).

For TortoiseHG the best solution would be to request a feature allowing *automatical* messages as you mention, some kind of template mechanism.

It has been requested here: [Template for commit message](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2234/template-for-commit-message) but not yet implemented as far as I can see.

Comment: So, how do I use create a commit template?

Comment: I've also seen suggestions such as `[alias]commit = commit -m "."`, but they are not working for me.

Comment: Like I said it does not seem like commit templates are implemented yet in TortoiseHG..